# How can you turn off pre-emptive when using basic auth in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

We've recent;y upgraded to Spring Boot 2.1 with associated spring security starter.

We are finding that web services (SOAP) secured by basic auth now default to using pre-emptive basic auth which is breaking some client code (we can't change the client code, it;s third party).

Is there any way to turn off pre-emptive, or fall back to the old behaviour ?

Comment: Does it really change? My understanding of *pre-emptive* is that the client is sending the credentials with the first request not waiting for the challenge response. That means a change of backend wouldn't change the *pre-emptive* behavior. Only a change of client would do it.

Comment: Could you add your request and response with header?

Comment: I'll ask the devs and get back to you